# max in query using my php admin doesn't give right value just the first one

Tags: java, max

This code for finding the max salary of an employee,the data stored in database in phpmyadmin using java in netbeans:

```
case 5:{//start of max salary 5
    RS = st.executeQuery("select * from firsttable  where having max(salary)");

    System.out.println("the employee with max salary: ");
    while (RS.next())
    {  //start while loop
        //retrieve data

       String []data = {RS.getString("ID"),
                        RS.getString("firstName"),
                        RS.getString("lastName"),
                        RS.getString("birthDate"),
                        RS.getString("salary"),
                        RS.getString("lastLogin")};

        {//start print data
        System.out.println("ID: "+data[0]);
        //System.out.println("ID int: "+RS.getInt("ID"));
        System.out.println("firstName: "+data[1]);
        System.out.println("lastName: "+data[2]);
        System.out.println("birthDate: "+data[3]);
        System.out.println("salary: "+data[4]);
        System.out.println("lastLogin: "+data[5]);
        }//end print data

    }//end while loop

    break;
}//end of max salary 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this query returns anything at all. What you are looking for is:

```
SELECT *
FROM firsttable
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM firsttable)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM firsttable
HAVING salary = MAX(salary)
```